# Asp.net core webapi connection error to mongo docker image when adding a docker file

Tags: mongodb, docker, asp.net-core

I developed a simple dotnet core api that connects to mongo docker image. The application works perfectly with the following uri (mongodb://localhost:27017) :
[mongo connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJkWO.png)

```
{
  "MongoDB": {
    "Database": "messagesdb",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 27017,
    "User": "",
    "Password": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

the JSON response
[Json Response after a successful run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAaVI.png)

But When I add a docker file via visual studio, and setting the host in the settings.json file to mongo instead of localhost, as the picture shows (mongodb://mongo:27017):
[mongo connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oju5N.png)

The Docker file :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ErrorMessagesAPI.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./ErrorMessagesAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ErrorMessagesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ErrorMessagesAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ErrorMessagesAPI.dll"]
```

The docker-compose for mongo :

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mongo:
      image: mongo
      container_name: mongo
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
      volumes:
        - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      container_name: mongo-express
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
      depends_on:
        - mongo  
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

The API doesn't work as the following picture depicts:
[docker run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUTdM.png), and the complete code can be found here [MessageAPI](https://github.com/eng-aomar/ErrorMessagesAPI)

I am following the article found here [Docker + MongoDB + .NET Core = a good tim](https://medium.com/@kristaps.strals/docker-mongodb-net-core-a-good-time-e21f1acb4b7b)
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The text "enter image description here" doesn't really describe your problem very well.  Can you edit your question to include the details necessary to reproduce the issue as text, not images, and directly in the question, not behind links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to share my solution for this problem, so you can benefit from your turn.
to link to the mongo image, you should update the docker-compose file, and leave the settings as-is. providing an environmental variable in the docker-compose will re-write the
settings in the settings.json file, as the following:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mongo
todo-server:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    environment:
      MongoDB__Host: mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```